# Springboot 2.7.1 : RestController returning 200 Status when the request param is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-17

I have the below SpringBoot Controller test which is working as expected and asserting 200 response

```
@GetMapping("/payment/list")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPaymentList(@RequestParam(value = "pageNum") Integer pageNum,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "pageSize") Integer pageSize,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "accountId") String accountId,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "sortParam") Integer sortParam) {
    PageableResult<PaymentDTO> paymentList = paymentService.getPaymentList(pageNum, pageSize, accountId, sortParam);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(paymentList);
}
```

Below is my test case

```
@Test
public void testfindAll() throws Exception {
    //Given
    Integer pageNum = 1;
    Integer pageSize = 5;
    String accountId = "testaccountId";
    Integer sortParam = 2;        
    PageableResult<PaymentDTO> result = gettestResult();

    //when
    Mockito.when(paymentService.getPaymentList(pageNum, pageSize, accountId, sortParam)).thenReturn(result);

    //Then
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .get("/payment/list")
                    .param("pageNum", pageNum.toString())
                    .param("pageSize", pageSize.toString())
                    .param("accountId", accountId)
                    .param("sortParam", sortParam.toString())                                                                      
    ).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();        
}
```

But when I comment out one of the request param as below in the console log I see 500 error but the test is still passing, can someone please help me understand why the controller is returning 200 Status but the body is giving 500 error?

```
 mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/payment/list")
                        .param("pageNum", pageNum.toString())
                        ///.param("pageSize", pageSize.toString())
                        .param("accountId", accountId)
                        .param("sortParam", sortParam.toString())                                                                  
        ).andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Console log for 500 error

```
2022-12-05 14:51:45.285[HW0015904][Test worker][ERROR][GlobalControllerExceptionHandler] - unexpected-error: request uri: [{E}/payment/list{/E}] exception: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'pageSize' for method parameter type Integer is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValueInternal(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"status":false,"errorCode":500,"errorMessage":"Internal Error!","result":null}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: Which handling do you have in `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler`?

Comment: Somewhere in your code(as Georgii suggested, in `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler`), you are catching exception and changing the status code to 200. Try to disable all exception handling and run test again to check this.

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov I didnt quite understand your question. I'm using `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`
`@SpringBootTest `annotations for my controller test class

Comment: @OTUser, in the first log line there is `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` class, I think that it is your custom exception handler, where you catch `MissingServletRequestParameterException` and apparently set 200 status